# How to print into a pdf file a graph generated in xmgrace?

Tags: pdf, graph, printing, xmgrace

I've a plot in xmgrace which I would like to save separately from the main project as a pdf file. The thing is that when I'm in the *print setup* selecting the *Device* there is no pdf option just the usual X11, PostScript, JPE, PNG, etc. Is there some way I can save graphs with a **.pdf** extension?

Thanks

[Device setup for printing in xmgrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faegu.png)

Answer (score 0):

For reasons unknown to me, some xmgrace pre-compiled binaries don't come with the "print to PDF" option (Ubuntu's binary is one example). In this case you either re-compile xmgrace (enabling the PDF output) or use a combination of commands to generate an eps and then convert it to pdf. This is what I use (with a Linux distro):

```
f=my_file
base=${f%.*}
LANG= xmgrace -hardcopy -hdevice EPS $f -printfile $base.eps
epstopdf $base.eps --outfile=$base.pdf
rm $base.eps
```

The `LANG=` is there to avoid localisation issues (with some locales the comma is used in place of the dot as decimal separator and I don't want that).
If you don't have `epstopdf` installed you can use any other software to do the conversion.